# Technet Terminal Server CAL Licensing

Tags: terminal-server, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

A company I contract to is considering purchasing a TechNet subscription. They seem pretty cheap, but they have a question that nobody seems to be able to answer.

A large part of the technet is for evaluating Server 2008 Terminal Services. I assume that on a TechNet OS (as it's the same as a normal OS, in all respects) that you need to activate the license server and install some CALs so that it doesn't run out in 120 days.

How does one go about activating the TS Licenses under a TechNet subscription? And will they need to purchase retail CALs in order to use them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, TechNet subscription product licenses are and always have been only for evaluation purposes.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/bb892759.aspx

Registering as a MS Partner and ordering the Action Pack gives you a limited number of internal use licenses, including TS CAL's, for running your business. In most cases you're afforded 10 internal use licenses.

https://partner.microsoft.com/40112699

Comment: Hi Joe, yes we realise they're for evaluation, but for a long-term evaluation 90 days won't cut it! Thanks for the info, I guess we'll find out when the subscription is activated.

Comment: P.S. That 2nd URL, the partner.microsoft one, answered a question that nobody I asked at Microsoft could. Thanks heaps!

Comment: More than happy to help.